# Python pandas memory leak with read csv

Tags: python, pandas, memory-leaks

I was processing a huge csv in chunks and noticed that it is gradually increasing memory. After a lot of print quit and profiling I think it is because of how pandas is creating new dataframes without deleting the previous one when reading from csv.

I used `pympler muppy` to profile.

Below i just read from csv 4 times iteration and it shows me the size of `pandas.core.frame.Dataframe` keeps on increasing

```
iterator = pd.read_csv(downloaded_file, chunksize=chunksize,
                                   compression='gzip', skipinitialspace=True, encoding='utf-8')
            i = 1
            for df in iterator:
                all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
                sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
                summary.print_(sum1)
                i += 1
                if i < 5:
                    continue
                break
```

This gives me below stats

```
                                types |   # objects |   total size
===================================== | =========== | ============
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           1 |      4.04 MB


                                types |   # objects |   total size
===================================== | =========== | ============
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           2 |      9.04 MB


                                types |   # objects |   total size
===================================== | =========== | ============
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           3 |      14.02 MB

                                types |   # objects |   total size
===================================== | =========== | ============
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           4 |      18.99 MB
```

I am processing 6 files each over 10 gb in 6 process through shell and multiple subprocesses through multiprocessing pool. According to my calculation each chunk i read is almost 2gb. So for lets say 12 process it should be 24 gb and add overhead 30 35gb.. But my  script is gradually increasing in memory and on random intervals it drops huge percent too. But when it reaches 60gb which is my server memory the whole script get killed.

This looks like there is some cleanup going on internally which is not linear.

Comment: Honestly sounds like a garbage collection problem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)
http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-does-python-manage-memory.htm